# Translating "in love and friendship forever"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I would like to inscribe this on my gravestone, in Latin: "in love and friendship forever." Could someone help me translate it?

Answer (score 9):

There are other phrases for 'forever', but I would choose that used by the poet Catullus in his beautiful and touching farewell poem at his brother's grave

I suggest *amor et amicitia in perpetuum.* Literally, this means 'love and frienship unceasing'.

Comment: I think _semper_ or _sempiternus_ sounds more positive than _perpetuum_, which reminds me of _cadena perpetua_ (in Spanish; it seems this word [did not make it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perpetuus#Descendants) into English).

Comment: @luchonacho We have in English _perpetual, perpetuate_ etc.(also, even, _sempiternal_).

Comment: *sempiternal* isn't related to *perpetuus*.

Comment: @NRitH Of course it isn't — and it's English, not Latin. Did you not notice that luchonacho referred to the Latin in his comment?

Answer (score 5):

I was originally going to suggest the same-ish answer as [@TomCotton](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/645/tom-cotton). However, since he has provided it already I am going to simply provide some suggestions concerning orthography, rather than translation, given that the phrase you requested is going to be displayed.

Classical Latin, at least when it was carved into stone (you indicated in your question that this was going to be engraved on a gravestone), typically carried the following characteristics.

- Written in all-caps.
- The letter *U* was written with *V*.
- Dipthongs *ae* and *oe* were often written as single characters.
- Instead of simply spacing words, they were often marked with an interpunct character, or the spaces were simply left out.
- Long vowels could be marked with apices.

With all that said, the wonderful suggestion from [@TomCotton](https://latin.stackexchange.com/users/645/tom-cotton) could be rendered as such

> AMORETAMICITIAINPERPETVVM
>   AMORETAMÍCITIAINPERPETVVM
>
> AMOR·ET·AMICITIA·IN·PERPETVVM
>   AMOR·ET·AMÍCITIA·IN·PERPETVVM

Comment: I would *definitely* use interpuncts rather than just omitting the spaces for this purpose, but omit the apices.  Otherwise, it looks good to me.

Comment: @varro I would generally agree; I am simply offering all options.

Comment: Accent marks are rare in inscriptions.

Comment: @NRitH I am aware of that. Again, I’m simply offering a set of options from which to choose.

Comment: Understood and upvoted.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone!  I really didn't want to screw up the inscription on my gravestone.  Now I won't.  Thanks again.